# Clear prompt on Esc in OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-yosemite

Clearing prompt in OS X Terminal is really annoying. We have <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> to clear before cursor and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to clear after cursor. Is there any way to clear whole prompt with <kbd>esc</kbd> key, like in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The built in options are either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> to go to the beginning of the line and clear it or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to cancel the current command.

If you go into your Terminal settings and look under Profiles > Keyboard you'll see the interface for creating custom keyboard shortcuts. Just create a new shortcut and set it to Send Text '\001\013' (or hit whatever command keys you want to use) and bind it to whatever key/combo you want.

Comment: How can I assign anything to ESC there? I don't see that key.

Comment: I don't think you can change the ESC binding from what I see. I have mine bound to CTRL + DEL.